# HTML5 video not playing

Tags: html

I tried a simple example for HTML5 but it doesnt seem to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls autoplay">
    <source src="resources/sample/sample1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried the example on chrome, the video loads up, but it does not play, i can see the video frames if i move the slider to and fro but the video itself doesnot play.

UPDATE:
I accessed this on localhost(tomcat), its still reacting in the same way.
Also i noticed that i am not able to play any HTML5 videos on chrome or firefox(updated).

Comment: This is not allowed for security reasons. Open the html file locally to view the video or upload the video to the server. Chrome will give this error: Not allowed to load local resource.

Comment: Even i am facing the same problem, The solution below is not possible by my program should scan the directories for videos and give an option to play, Please see the below question and help me resolve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834173/html-5-video-tag-not-working-from-tomcat-edited/16834215?noredirect=1#comment24274462_16834215

Answer (score 14):

Add "controls" as a flag. It allows the browser to run it's own player code on the video. I tried this with a .mp4 file on Chrome and it works.

Comment: Had the same issue as OP. I was providing `autoplay` and `loop` but was omitting the `controls` prop. The only thing now is I get an annoying video player frame on my page so maybe I'll just use a GIF instead.

Answer (score 5):

I do not agree with Alex Pereora.  It can be loaded from local machine just by referencing file names and or paths.

I had similar issue, and turned out IIS in Win 7 Pro does not have mp4 in it's mime types.  Must add add the mime type.  see instructions for adding mime type in link below.

[html5 video is not playing mp4 error "Invalid Source"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079808/html5-video-is-not-playing-mp4-error-invalid-source/)

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue now. I am getting the `src` of the video dynamically and asynchronously using ajax.

The issue was that the `<video>` element was getting loaded before the `src`. If we put the `<video>` element into the DOM after the `src` is loaded then the issue will get fixed.

In case of Angular we can use `*ngIf` to fix the issue. Below is Angular code snippet:

```
<video autoplay *ngIf="src" class="thumbnail">
  <source [src]="src" [type]="type">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to convert the mp4 format from V1 to V2:

`ffmpeg.exe -i old.mp4 -brand mp42 new-v2.mp4`

Comment: That actually works surprisingly. Even without "-brand mp42". Do you know why this is working?

Answer (score 3):

You can't load a localfile like that with the HTML5 Video tag. 
You'll have to use a localhost or a distant hosted file. Try to install mamp/wamp and load it through the virtual host.

```
<source src="http://localhost/development/programs/html/html5/sample/sample1.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: i have made some changes, issue still there, i have updated the question

Comment: I disagree. To play a `HTML5` video you don't need a localhost, it can run simply from your desktop, i/e both HTML file and video resource being present locally.

Answer (score 3):

use both format it works fine in all browser:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="unbelievable.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your type of video is MP4 running on IIS/.NET

Add a web.config file to the root of the application `web.config` with the following contents

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/mp4" />
       </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach will surely work.

```html
<video width="50%" height="50%" loop muted id = "autoplay">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>   
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById("autoplay").play()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to work as long as the `muted` flag is added (no need for `play()`).

Answer (score 1):

add `autoplay loop` to video tag for play automatically as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
  <source src="resources/sample/sample1.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Video not playing in server because the mime type is not added in IIS.

To add Mime Type :

•   Go to IIS and select your site

•   Click Mime Types Under menu and click Add on right side tab

•   Under File Name Extension add mp4,under Mime type add video/mp4 and click Ok.

•   Restart IIS ,Now run the application

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a relative uri for your video. The "D:/…" only works on windows locally and not in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome: Does the file contain audio as well? If so and you are playing it on desktop, connect the speakers to the desktop and check.

Firefox: H.264 content is not supported

IE9: The following should be added to your page `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to video encoding.Check the encoding of your video and see if Chrome supports that.It may be a possible reason as I faced it.
Try some encoders like ff-mpeg to encode videos.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when hosting on IIS, and found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274486/iis-returns-404-not-found-for-mp4-files).
In my case, even putting complete video URL on Chrome would give me 404 error, because the MP4 MIME type didn't exist on site config. So, I added .mp4 with MIME video/mp4, and all got right. Dunno if that's the same with tomcat, but that's worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

Just set controls as a flag, not as a key=value pair:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="resources/sample/sample1.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that you had inserted the video path correctly. Your 'resources' folder and the page where is the video tag must be at the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, chrome requires the video to have muted attribute in order to play or autoplay.