# html5 video is not playing mp4 error "Invalid Source"?

Tags: html

I am trying HTML5 video tag and I have downloaded a Microsoft sample and trying to run it but a strange thing is happening, and it is that it plays video coming from a URL (commented tag) but for local mp4 file it do not shows error and shows message "Invalid Source"

Here is my code please guide me what I should do to make it run local file correctly ?

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<video src="http://www.bing.com/az/hprichv/?p=Butterfly_Clipcanvas_223479_EN-US.mp4"
        autoplay loop>
    </video>-->
    <video controls src="hprichv.mp4" width="300" height="200" autoplay loop>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Web page and video files both reside in the same folder.

Comment: Is the local file playable normally in other multimedia players?

Comment: Probably being returned with the wrong mime type. What do the response headers say when loading the file locally?

Comment: @MrLister, yes it is played in multimedia players.

Comment: @steveax, it do not run locally in web but I can run it in media player. I have not set mime type anywhere infect this is the whole code. As I mentioned strange thing is that file coming from URL is being played.

Comment: Does it fail to work on all the browsers? If it worked for any one particular browser, then please specify that.

Comment: @PankajParashar it do not work in any browser.

Answer (score 19):

Im on Windows 7 Pro.  I develop locally and then host/serve remotely.  Trying to load a local mp4 file while developing locally ran into this identical situation. No combination of using  localhost/myvideo.mp4 or 127.0.0.1/myvideo.mp4 or /aaa/myvideo.mp4 or myvideo.mp4 in same directory as file got things to work...but referencing a full URL like `http://www.mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4` did, as above.

On local machine, Chrome shows no error messages...just shows black box with controls. No clues as to whats up.  Switched to IE and it showed the black box and controls and the error message. 'Invalid source'

I focused on @steveax question and Mime types.

Turns out IIS in this version of windows/IIS does not have a MIME type setup for .mp4.  No clue why not...but not.

To add the MP4 MIME type, open *Internet Information Services* (IIS) Manager and follow these steps:

- Highlight **Default Web Site** on the left panel;
- Double-click **MIME Types** on the right panel;
- Scroll down the list and notice that there is no **.mp4**;
- On the right panel again, click **Add**: at the first field, write `.mp4` and on the field below write `video/mp4`
- Click OK and you are done.

Restart IIS!

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem and found that the video codec was not supported.

Get a video converter software (like Oxelon - it is free) and choose the output to be .mp4 (even is the source is .mp4). Choose the video codec to be "H264" and the audio codec to be "AAC".
This will solve your problem.

Comment: In my case I had used ffmpeg to encode an MP4 using the -acodec mp2 flag. I change this to -acodec libvo_aacenc and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

**For Internet Explorer**

I used FormatFactory, setting up AAC encoding for audio and H264 for output for the mp4 format, in "High Quality and big size"

**For Google Chrome**

I converted my original video to the `webm` format thanks to *Free WebM Video Converter* (make sure you uncheck everything that would like to install ads).

It took a long time but then it worked in Chrome.

```
<video controls>
  <source src="thevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="thevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it's just with IE 11.  Firefox works great.

On IE, if I go to Compatibility View and add "localhost" to the list, the box disappears altogether.