# HTML5 - .mp4 video fails to load as a resouce in browser?

Tags: html, video

I have a simple HTML5 page that has a .mp4 video file on the page using the video tag. In my development environment, the video works as it should in the browser and plays.

When I upload the files to my staging environment, the video does not work, and gives a console error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://staging-url-here.com/videos/MyVideo.mp4
```

All files are in the correct locations within the folders, so I have no idea why this video works fine when I test in my own development browser, but fails to load in staging.

Can anyone provide insight as to why this would occur?

Index.html

```
<video class="img-responsive" id="video" poster="images/PosterImg.PNG"  />
       <source src="videos/MyVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Folder Structure

C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Project1\MyWebsite\Index.html

C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Project1\MyWebsite\videos\MyVideo.mp4

Comment: Show us the HTML5 part where your video is declared...

Comment: Shortly you'll receive a downvote - Your information isn't suffice... (I don't downvote unless really necessary, so no downvote from me...)

Comment: @Fusseldieb Added html

Comment: Now it's a bit better, but... We need a thing more.. Your folder structure. Show me in which path is the video and in which is the HTML file.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Added folder structure

Comment: What is your staging environment? If you are developing on Windows, but your staging system is a Linux machine, then double-check upper-/lowercase letters for correctness.

Comment: Here it seems to have the answer you need/want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079808/html5-video-is-not-playing-mp4-error-invalid-source/ - I don't know **if** this is the solution, but it might be. The way you showed us all thos things, it should work... So, +1 from me...

Comment: @Fusseldieb I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @CBroe I am not sure about the environment, I will have to check with my team.

Comment: @Fusseldieb I follow the steps from that post on my development machine, but that did not seem to solve the issue

Comment: assuming that the path is correct, do you have the relevant MIME types defined on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file permission on staging, If your development environment is different from staging and production then this is a general situation