# New to html, can't get video to play in browser?

Tags: html, css, video, web, html5-video

I am unable to get my video to play in browser when I click the "play" button. I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!

```
<video poster= "videoposter.jpg" width="40%" height="40%" controls= "controls">
   <source src="video/phone.mp4"  type='video/mp4'/> 
   <source src="video/phone.webm" type='video/webm; codecs"vp8, vorbis"'  />
   <source src="video/phone.ogv"  type='video/ogv; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/> 

      Your browser doesn't support the video element in HTML5.
    </video>
```

Comment: a screenshot of your developer console could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Youtube video source into HTML5 video tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons could be :

```
1). File path of video isn't correct. Look at developer console in browser to get this rectified.
2). IIS in Win 7 Pro does not have mp4 in it's mime types. Must add add the mime type. see instructions for adding mime type in link below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079808/html5-video-is-not-playing-mp4-error-invalid-source/
```

Comment: I spent a couple of hours wondering why it wouldn't work, but it was the file path that was incorrect. What a silly mistake. Thank you so much!