# ASP.NET MVC application, HTML video does not work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, video

I've encountered this problem:
I've just started to learn ASP.NET, created a simple application, and I need to play a video on one of the pages, here is a code in cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Player";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <video width="1020" height="780" controls="controls">
        <source src="file:///E:/Video/ActCAM/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
<h2>Player</h2>
```

And, unfortunately, I see just a black box with a few controls on it which don't work, instead of a video. (I found a similar question [html5 video is not playing mp4 error "Invalid Source"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079808/html5-video-is-not-playing-mp4-error-invalid-source/) , but that didn't work for me) 
I've specified a file on the local PC just for testing, web-application is also running on a local machine. However, if I change `"file:///E:/Video/ActCAM/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4"` to something like this: `http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4` (it's just a sample free video found on the internet), it works fine. Also, if I create just a simple HTML file with the following code:

```
<video width="1020" height="780" controls="controls">
        <source src="file:///E:/Video/ActCAM/test2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
```

it works fine.
Please, help me!

Comment: When a web-page is served from a web-server you cannot use `file://` URIs, even if it's `localhost`. When a web-page is opened directly from disk you _can_ use `file://` URIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was a reason of my problem, thank you very much @Dai
 and @Alexandre F. Malavasi Cardoso !
The only thing I need to do, was to change `file:///E:/Video/ActCAM/test2.mp4` to `~/Content/Video/test2.mp4` and transfer file to that directory

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is running perfectly on local because in that case your browser and the server are in the same machine. So, the path file:///E:/Video/ActCAM/test2.mp4 works fine.

However, when you publish the application in a real Web server, this path should be accessible by the browser. So, the video file should have a valid URL using http or https protocol.

So, once the application is published, that path in the frontend for the video (and other media types) should be not a physical path, but a virtual one (mydomain.com/video/myVideo.mp4)