# HTML 5 Video Tag not working from Tomcat (Edited)

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

Video not playing from the Tomcat 7 server using absolute path & relative path of the file:

Edit Summary: Altered the example for the relative path, and i am placing the videos inside application Root-Folder (Still not able to resolve the video bug).

We are building a small application for video viewing for local usage. As HTML-5 gives us tremendous support for video viewing we opted to write a program using simple Servlet/JSP,  deploy it on **Tomcat 7 Web server**.

The Application logic is as follows:

1. Root path (Absolute Path) is set to a root folder of my application in tomcat.
2. All the files and directories inside root are displayed with a 'go' button beside.
3. If a video file in the folder is selected by clicking 'go', a video viewing page appears.
4. The relative of the video file is supplied to the video page using Expression langauge (EL) to the source of video tag.
5. Video should be played from the localhost's hard disk to all the browser end points.

The Problem I am facing is my video is not playing from tomcat server, but the same rendered 'source' code of html on a browser when copied and pasted on a file the video is working fine. How to make it work from tomcat server?

After Edit: I modified my app to adjust for a relative path inside tomcat myapp's root folder, still it is not working. Below is the edited question.

**Screen shorts of my app are:**

---

**Stage One: Click the Link**

[image: Stage One]

---

**Stage Two: Select the video or folder to browse**

[image: Stage Two]

---

**Stage Three: Play the Video** *(Here I am getting Error)*
[image: Stage Three]

---

**Server Rendered the following HTML on the browser(Copied from view source):**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enjoy the Video</h1>

    <video controls autoplay width="512" height="288">
        <source src="G:\\To-See\\Ravi_sir_joke.m4v"> </source>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

---

When the Same source is copied and pasted on a sample html page anywhere in the computer the video works fine. The below image proves that.

[image: Expected Output]

---

**After Edit:** The server rendered proper relative path which contains the video.
The video is not working yet.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enjoy the Video</h1>

    <video controls autoplay width="512" height="288">
        <source src="../ROOT-VIDEO/Ravi_sir_joke.m4v" > </source>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

**The video is present in my application's root directory:**

[image: Tomcat root-video root]

I have pasted the edited program in this page for reference. Please correct me and help me clear the video bug.

---

---

Program

**Package Structure:**

[image: Package Structure]

---

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <!-- <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/welcome.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> -->

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.cluster.vapp.controller.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

---

**Controller Servlet:**

```
   package com.cluster.vapp.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.FileUtil;
import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.SearchResult;
import com.cluster.vapp.service.VappService;
import com.cluster.vapp.service.VappServiceImpl;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private VappService service;

    public void init() throws ServletException {

        service = new VappServiceImpl();
    }

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String strServletPath = request.getServletPath();

        // debug
        System.out.println(strServletPath);
        // end of debug
        int intServletpath = 0;

        if (strServletPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/welcome.do")) {

            intServletpath = 1;

        }

        if (strServletPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/verify.do")) {

            intServletpath = 2;

        }

        if (strServletPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/searchRoot.do")) {

            intServletpath = 3;

        }

        switch (intServletpath) {

        case 1: {// welcome.do

            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("./JSP/welcome.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

            break;
        }

        case 2: { // verify.do

            if (service.isVideoFile(request.getParameter("path_name"))) {

                String strVideoPath = service.findRelative(request
                        .getParameter("path_name"));
                request.setAttribute("VIDEO_PATH", FileUtil.adjustPathName(strVideoPath));
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                        .getRequestDispatcher("./JSP/video.jsp");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }

            else {

                List<SearchResult> listSearchResults = service
                        .searchDirectory(request.getParameter("path_name"));
                request.setAttribute("LIST_SEARCH_RESULT", listSearchResults);
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                        .getRequestDispatcher("./JSP/search.jsp");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }

            break;
        }

        case 3: {// searchRoot.do

            List<SearchResult> listSearchResults = service
                    .searchRootDirectory();
            request.setAttribute("LIST_SEARCH_RESULT", listSearchResults);

            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("./JSP/search.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            break;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

---

**VappServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.cluster.vapp.service;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.FileUtil;
import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.SearchResult;

public class VappServiceImpl implements VappService{

    public static final String ROOT_PATH = "F:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\\webapps\\balaji\\ROOT-VIDEO";
    public static final String BASE_PATH = "F:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\\webapps\\balaji";

    public List<SearchResult> searchRootDirectory() {

        List<String> listDirectoryNames = FileUtil.fetchFileNames(ROOT_PATH);

        List<SearchResult> listSearchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();

        for (String dirName : listDirectoryNames) {
            SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
            result.setStrName(dirName);
            result.setStrPath(ROOT_PATH + "\\" + dirName);
            listSearchResults.add(result);
        }

        return listSearchResults;
    }

    public boolean isVideoFile(String pStrPath) {

        File file = new File(pStrPath);

        // System.out.println("Is file There: " + file.exists());

        if (file.isFile())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public List<SearchResult> searchDirectory(String pStrPath) {

        List<String> listDirectoryNames = FileUtil.fetchFileNames(pStrPath);

        List<SearchResult> listSearchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();

        for (String dirName : listDirectoryNames) {
            SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
            result.setStrName(dirName);
            result.setStrPath(pStrPath + "\\" + dirName);
            listSearchResults.add(result);
        }

        return listSearchResults;
    }

    public String findRelative(String pStrVideoPath){

        return FileUtil.findRelativePath(BASE_PATH, pStrVideoPath);
    }

}
```

---

**FileUtil.java**

```
package com.cluster.vapp.fileutils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.exceptions.InvalidAbsolutePathException;
import com.cluster.vapp.fileutils.exceptions.InvalidDirectoryNameException;

/**
 * @author Balaji.K.R
 * 
 * @version 1.0
 * 
 *          The class Contains methods for various file operations. All methods
 *          present will accept only absolute string path of the source and
 *          destination file structure.
 * 
 */
public class FileUtil {

    /**
     * The Method returns the names of the files as a list, in the path given.
     * 
     * Note: The path name should be a absolute path, and should be a existing
     * directory. Any violation will lead to corresponding run-time exception.
     * 
     * 
     * @param pStrDirectory
     *            Location of the directory where it needs to be searched.
     * @return List of file names as string existing in the directory.
     */
    public static List<String> fetchFileNames(String pStrDirectory) {
        List<String> listFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        File directory = new File(pStrDirectory);

        if (directory.isAbsolute() == false) {
            throw new InvalidAbsolutePathException(
                    "Directory Path is not Absolute");
        }

        if ((directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()) == false) {
            throw new InvalidDirectoryNameException();
        }

        String[] strFileNames = directory.list();

        for (String name : strFileNames) {

            listFileNames.add(name);
        }

        return listFileNames;
    }

    public static String adjustPathName(String pStrPath) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pStrPath);
        sb.insert(0, "../");

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static String findRelativePath(String pStrBasePath,
            String pStrAbsolutePath) {

        return new File(pStrBasePath).toURI()
                .relativize(new File(pStrAbsolutePath).toURI()).getPath();

    }

}
```

---

**welcome.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Cluster Video Application</h1>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <h1><a href="./searchRoot.do">Browse Videos</a></h1>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**search.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="jstl"%>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> function submitForm(form){form.submit();} </script>
<style type="text/css"> div.label{font-size: 30px; color: blue; margin: 10px;} </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Click to proceed...</h1>

    <jstl:forEach var="result"
                items="${requestScope.LIST_SEARCH_RESULT}">

    <form action="./verify.do" method="post">
        <div class="label">
            ${result.strName} <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="submitForm(this.form);"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="path_name" value="${result.strPath}">
        </div>
    </form>


    </jstl:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**video.jsp**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enjoy the Video</h1>

    <video controls autoplay width="512" height="288">
        <source src="${requestScope.VIDEO_PATH}"> </source>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<source src="G:\\To-See\\Ravi_sir_joke.m4v">` , it should be replaced with some path in the webserver with full context path .

Comment: What is the Webserver context path for tomcat 7?
Guide me and i will change in my program.

Comment: Put the video under some folder under the root folder of your application and give its path to source.

Comment: I cant put that...that's the requirement. 
Tomcat will be in one drive and the videos will be in another partitioned drive.

Comment: I tried making the root folder inside my tomcat webapp, application path. Still it Dint work.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I have edited the example, but the same problem persists.
Can you check for the bug and find a solution. (I have changed from absolute path to relative path as you suggested)

Answer (score 3):

That's for security reason. Pages loaded from some server can't load files from local drive. Copy video to src/main/webapp/video.m4v. Change JSP to this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Cluster Video App</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enjoy the Video</h1>

    <video controls autoplay width="512" height="288">
        <source src="<c:url value="/video.m4v" />"> </source>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to solve it ?
Can you guide me and change the settings so that i can access?

Comment: Sorry It dint work. The rendered HTML copied from page source is: <video controls autoplay width="512" height="288">
  <source src="<c:url value="G:\\To-See\\Ravi_sir_joke.m4v" />" > </source>
 </video>

Comment: The 'src' attribute in the source cant be tag, it should be a path.
All i have now on that page is Absolute path of the page. How to use it to bring the video on screen

Comment: notice also the first line. but it looks like your jsp is not processed. just printed in raw form.

Comment: I have edited the example, but the same problem persists.
Can you check for the bug and find a solution. (I have changed from absolute path to relative path)

Answer (score 0):

place the the folder inside your **WebContent** folder or **webapps** folder then give path like 
**./folder1/file.mp4**
if **WebContent** is not there then create a new project setup using eclipse with **DynamicWebProject** paste the tour files inside that.

i am also getting this issue but now its **[SOLVED]** 
and i am using **tomcat 8 and java 7**

Answer (score 0):

How about check the video.js
It really works. I tested with Apache-Tomcat 8.5.

First, include these two lines

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video.min.js"></script>
```

and use video tag like this.

```
<video
    id="my-player"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
    data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4#t=5,10" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type="video/ogg"></source>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
    web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
      supports HTML5 video
    </a>
  </p>
</video>
```