# Custom scrub bar in video HTML5, set currentTime not working

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-player

I'm making a custom scrub bar in HTML video player. I'm creating a HTML5 video player and take a currentTime from video and it is working good, but seting currentTime after moving a scrub bar dose not working.

Firstly, I want write I've tried several possiblity to resolve this problem. I disable autoplay in video and other things, what can be.

But, one thing puzzles me. I can not have a directly URL to the video, I have a URL to JSP code on the server, and this code return to me this file. What can be a problem with it? Because, if I downloaded this movie file and set URL to directly to this movie file -  with extension .mp4 - all starts working good.

Maybe it's problem with it I can not have a directly url to movie file?

I don't have any ideas to resolve this porblem. I'm counting on your help

Comment: can you please add some minimal code example to your question?

Comment: This is a sample code what I'm using. I can't publish a video. This is privacy policy my company.

https://codepen.io/proper93/pen/yZMQLB

Comment: is the video stored as an .mp4 video file format?

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834173/html-5-video-tag-not-working-from-tomcat-edited/16834215?noredirect=1#comment24274462_16834215

Answer (score 0):

if the video stored as an .mp4 or .ogg or .webm video file format, It would play. Here is how your html may look like.

```html
    <video controls preload="metadata">
        <source src="http://www.example.com/waterfall-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://www.example.com/waterfall-video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Video not supported.
    </video>
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution is not working. I don't have a URL like you, what is ending with file extension. My URL to movie file, is something like this: http://camera.system.example.url/file.cam?id=22496966&camid=16741 and I think it is a problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But, if I download a file movie from this url and put an url to this file in the same JS code all is working good.

Comment: I can't take you a real url to the movie. Privacy policy, you know.