# Storing and playing local files with JavaScript and HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, audio

I am working on a media player, and I want to be able to queue local files in an array, play it, and even export it as a playlist (for later import).

I found this question, with a lot of helpful information:
[Using local file for Web Audio API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074833/using-local-file-for-web-audio-api-in-javascript)
However, the Base64 method would make the playlist too big, and the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074833/using-local-file-for-web-audio-api-in-javascript/18083202#18083202) solution creates a sandboxed file link (which are deleted from the browser when the session is closed).

Is there any good way to do this?

EDIT: Here's an example of what I want:

```
var playlist = {'file:///home/user/music/track1.mp3','file:///home/user/music/track2.mp3','file:///home/user/music/track3.mp3'};
```

It doesn't have to look like this, i just want something similar.

Comment: You want the files to be saved somewhere ,even when the session is closed?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK I want to reference files on the user's harddisk, so he can make a playlist and load it up again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try localstorage feature on html5.
Its helps store data even after the session is expired.

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
>
> http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

What i did in my music player,was store the file data path in the localstorage.
And whenever i needed it ,i retrieved it and replaced the current song with the one i wanted.

> // Store 
>     localStorage.setItem("Path","file:///home/user/music/track1.mp3'");
>
> //Retrieve
>   currentSong=localStorage.getItem('Path');

For multiple songs,u could create objects and do similar to this:
[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Will test this out when I get home! Can i export the full localStorage to a file? I could use this to store the whole playlist.

Comment: You can transfer the entire object file stored in localStorage as JSON format into a file.
Do check the last link i provided.
That helped me do my project. :)
And do accept my answer if it helped you out. :)

Comment: I tried your method ( http://jsfiddle.net/Tv8Cm/56/ ), but I get error "`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///file.mp3`" When trying to load the file. Is there issues with my code?

Comment: I think you should check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813408/html5-video-not-playing

Am 100% sure,the methode i told will work.
Just google when u have future doubts.
Its all there.

Comment: By the way,if you have further doubts,accept the answer if it helped and create a new question,cause it will be tough answering here in the comments..

Comment: I guess it helped, so have your check :)

Comment: Hi there, can you provide working fiddle or link to your player? As i am pretty sure that you can not really reuse saved file path